# Duplicate tuples in tuple relational calculus

Tags: database, tuple-relational-calculus

Suppose we have a relation Student(Name,Marks) with 2 tuples (a,100) and (a,100).
Now if I have a expression like :-
{ t.Name, t.Marks | Student(t) and t.Marks=100) . Then will I get both tuples or only a single tuple?

I know that in relation algebra we use project operator which removes duplicates .

I couldn't find a reference which says that in tuple relational calculus we don't consider duplicates.

Comment: Whatever reference you are using for calculus (namely?), find its definition for "relation". Because a {...} expression denotes one. While you're at it find their definition for {...}, which will tell you how, when some names denote relations, a {...} denotes a relation in terms of the named ones. PS Projection doesn't "remove duplicates". (Reasonably it "removes attributes".) It returns certain relations based on others. The "remove duplicates" is part of certain descriptions of what projection returns that talk in terms of manipulating *non-relations* that sometimes correspond to relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relations are defined as sets, not tables/bags. That means relations don't have multiple identical tuples.

Representing the same number/value/fact twice doesn't mean I represented two different numbers/values/facts.

Comment: Let's say two tuples are (a,100) and (a,95). Now these two tuples are not identical. Now if I need only the name of the students whose marks are greater than 90 then will "a" appear twice or only once if I use tuple relational calculus ?

Comment: If your resulting relation contains only student names, then you'll get `a` only once